# Creating bean in xml from another module not found

Tags: java, spring

I want to declare bean in xml like this:
`<bean  id="myClass" class="com.project.MyClass"/>`

But when I run this then I get: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.MyClass`

Tried to add: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.project">` but didn't help.

What should I do to get the class as a bean?

EDIT:
xml configuration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml" })
```

applicationContext-test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- setup properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application-test.properties" />

    <!-- import spring context -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/springContext.xml" />

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/inMemoryH2Context.xml" />

    <bean  id="myClass" class="com.project.MyClass"/>
</beans>
```

application-test.properties:

```
parameters... like for example: datasource.schema.prefix=eplcore.
```

META-INF/spring/springContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <!-- spring context configuration -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties,classpath:scheduler.properties,classpath:batch-jobs.properties,classpath:oauth2-clients.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="com.xxx.Db2Dao" type="assignable" />
        <context:exclude-filter expression="com.xxx.H2CDao" type="assignable" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.repository" />

    <!-- conditional cache context import -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/cache/springCache.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: post you XML configuration so we understand more clear

Comment: If the class isn't found it doesn't exists in the class path. Make sure you have the jar file from the other project on your classpath if not you cannot use the class.

Comment: Posted configuration.

Comment: Java ClassNotFoundException means that your class is not on the classpath.

If you use maven then you can check which classes are on your classpath with this command: mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt